# notifyDataSetChanged() show me a different view compared to setAdapter() method

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

Everyone!
 I've got a quite interesting problem when I am using a `ListView`. When I call `setAdapter()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()`, I got different views. In fact, the difference is only about the `magin` parameters of items. So, is there something different between the two method?

P.S. 
Please don't tell me this is duplicate with [notifyDataSetChanged vs setAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301677/notifydatasetchanged-vs-setadapter). I am looking forward to understanding the exception leading to the different views, while that question is focusd on the different cost of the two method.

Comment: have you check on internet before posting this question here on forum?look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301677/notifydatasetchanged-vs-setadapter an old interest not a new one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't think my problem is same as that one. I am talking about the different views got by the two methods, while that guy is focused on the difference of the cost. Maybe, there is something useful for me in that page, but, is there somehing talking about my question? I can't find it.